# How to breed a horse

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you breed horses in Minecraft?

Do you just spawn one in creative mode right on top of another one or something like that?

Comment: For future references: 1. Do not add tags that have nothing to do with your question. 2. Make some effort when writing a question; everybody makes mistakes, but that was beyond ridiculous.

Comment: The question you linked does not have an answer to this one.

Comment: Then you should comment on the accepted answer on that question, asking them to update it for the latest version of minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

First, I believe you need to tame both horses.  Then, you need two golden apples or golden carrots. (Made with gold bars.) The rest is the same as breeding cows except you use the apples or carrots.

Answer (score 1):

Craft a golden carrot with golden nuggets around a carrot in a crafting table.
Right click on both (horse + donkey/horse + horse/donkey + donkey etc.).

They will both breed and a smaller horse will appear.
Give the smaller horse bread, wheat, hay bales or sugar for them to grow faster.